# Changing p-value in lm() function in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

Is there any way to change the default p-value of 0.05 in lm() to 0.01? I'm running multiple linear regressions and want to account for that.

I tried adding p.adjust() but it didn't work since it's its own function.

Or is there a different function that I can run my linear regressions and adjust the p-value?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean change the default p-value of 0.05?

Comment: There is no threshold p-value in `lm()`.  Do you mean you want to change the assignment of 'significance stars' ? (They're hard-coded [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/library/stats/R/anova.R#L150-L153), so that will be a little tricky although not impossible.) Can you clarify?

Comment: If you just want to change the significance stars in your output then using a package like {modelsummary} might be the easiest way to do that.

Comment: It turns out you can't but we went a different way. Thank you all anyway!